# Conflict with wp_homeurl, wp_siteurl and admin interface settings

Tags: wp-config, virtual-hosts

I'm starting wordpress development, and learning the platform. 
Now I'm stuck with a strange issue. 
I have created a virtual host configuration that works as expected. 
I'm using xip.io for dns resolution, that also works as expected I can access wordpress application from other devices.

The thing that puzzles me is that if I define WP_HOMEURL and WP_SITEURL variables to the same values that are set via admin->options -> general settings the whole thing breaks. Nothing works anymore, I have to go directly to the database to reset site_url field.

The virtual host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example_dot_com
    DocumentRoot "C:/server/wp/wordpress"
    ServerName theme.local
    ServerAlias local.191.161.3.101.xip.io
    ErrorLog "logs/test1.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test1.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Settings in the admin UI

```
WordPress Address (URL) :  http://local.191.161.3.101.xip.io
Site Address (URL)  :  http://local.191.161.3.101.xip.io
```

I thought that those values are the same, and that it makes no difference how you define them (`wp-config.php` or via admin interface)?

Obviusly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what is it.

Comment: What do your `wp-config.php` lines look like?

Comment: `
      define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'local.192.168.3.101.xip.io');      
      define( 'WP_HOMEURL', 'local.192.168.3.101.xip.io' );
    
`

Comment: edit: somehow back tick don't work for code formating.

Comment: You did something wrong. Backticks do work in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants you need to define are [`WP_HOME`, not `WP_HOMEURL`, and `WP_SITEURL`,](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php) and you need to complete address. Your addresses are missing the [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)-- `http://`

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://local.192.168.3.101.xip.io'); 
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://local.192.168.3.101.xip.io' );
```

Without the scheme, WordPress treats those URIs like relative addresses. You can see that in the address bar if you watch what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that all I needed was a fresh pair of eyes.
Even when I was posting the code here I didn't notice that I'm missing http:// scheme.
Also the variable name....